# npm run dev not working with ubuntu(react-redux-universal-hot-example)

Tags: react-redux

I have logged an issue on github with console log 
https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/1344

I have clone this project and did npm install. I am using ubuntu. Its working fine on Window system.
First day it was working fine. But when I run second day it was not working.
Things that I have already tried to fix this..

1. Delete all node module and reinstall again.
2. Delete webpack-assets.json
3. Tried with node version (v5.6.0, v6.0.0, v6.9.0)
4. Clone again new project and install everything again

I have tried above all but still its not working for me. Please suggest me if I need to do anything else or you have any fix for this.
Logs.

Answer (score 0):

After long efforts I have find out the solution. I have just increase the inotify max_user_watch limit.
https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers

Thank you